# Is it correct that functional dependencies are not symmetrical?

Tags: database-design

Say we have a relation `R(A, B, C)`. We have one known functional dependency: A → B. I'm wondering if it's true that there would be no way to prove that A → B implies B → A. If it was true, I can't think of a proof with Armstrong's axioms. Is there a name for this? I believe asymmetry and antisymmetry state something stronger.

A → B says that any tuple sharing the same values of the attribute A must have the same values of the attribute B.

Thus this relation is valid:

```
A B C
1 1 1
1 1 2
2 2 1
```

But then so is this one:

```
A B C
1 1 1
1 1 2
2 1 1
```

Because the tuple `(2, 1, 1)` does not violate A → B.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. A proof that A → B does not imply B → A is your counterexample.